# tinymce - vnc paste issue in Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, tinymce, copy-paste, vnc

I have the weirdest problem:
When I copy a few lines from realVNC (from linux xterm) to tinymce textarea in Chrome, every cluster of blank spaces are collapsed into one (also in the full example given in the tinymce website). In any other browser it works perfect (also in any non tinymce textarea input in Chrome)
Even weirder is the fact that if I paste just a part of a line with a few adjacent blank spaces, it also works good, but if I mark a few lines, it appears wrong.

Example:
"sdf     sdf" - when just copying that text.
"sdf sdf" - when copying the entire line.

I spent 4-5 hours looking for a solution, but I came up empty (I usually a master in finding solutions over the internet)...

Can anyone please help, this really bugs my and my entire group (~25 people)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to paste into word first then copy that and paste into tinymce, it is either stripping the whitespace or not converting it to none blank white spaces.